GitLab CI/CD runners registration issues
I have several projects in local GitLab instance, no problems with connecting runners to those. I am trying to register a runner for the new GitLab project, which is deployed on the same instance. Also VM on which runner is created serve runners to other projects.
However, when I execute command sudo gitlab-runner register, then pass the URL and token, I get a following error (real url removed):

ERROR: Registering runner... failed status=couldn't execute POST against https://{here_my_instance.com}  Gateway Timeout PANIC: Failed to register the runner.

This suggests some network issues, however the same particula VM works perfectly fine providing runners to other projects. Also, for the project I am working on, the other VMs are totally okay and allows to register the runners.
What might be the issue here?
